# How to repair a window screen frame?

Tags: repair, windows, frame

I need to repair a metal window screen frame - not the screen itself, the frame that holds the screen.

I dropped the frame and it broke apart at one corner.

On closer inspection, I see a 90 degree plastic clip inside the frame that split in two.

[image: This is a picture of one half of the broken plastic clip]

[image: And this is the other half at a 90 degree angle.]

I think the best way to repair this is to replace the plastic fastener. I don't think glue would hold up to the stress when I put the screen into the frame.

Can someone tell me where to get the correct plastic clip, or failing that, recommend a glue that would hold it together?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Search for "screen frame corner keys".    Also any decent local hardware store should have these and/or do the repair for you.  I replace my broken window parts from [this place](https://www.swisco.com/cl/Corner-Keys)

Answer (score 2):

You need screen corners, but you'll have to figure out which ones you need based on the size of the channel in your frame.  (Obviously there are a variety of different frame extrusions out there from various manufacturers.)

Here's something to get you started:
https://windowscreenpros.com/parts-and-supplies/screen-hardware/plastic-miter-cut-screen-frame-corners/
[https://www.amazon.com/Plastic-Miter-Screen-Frame-Corners/dp/B008W9JTLW](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B008W9JTLW)

Answer (score 0):

This depends a lot on where you live.  Many times the local hardware stores have the items for these type of repairs where as the bigbox stores do not.

Some hardware stores provide rebuild services for screens. The only other option would be removing the 2 broken pieces and doing a google search for that part.

Also, my area has mobile services that repair or replace screens that are very reasonably priced.  A common name is "Screen Man"  and  "New Screens"

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The problem with a Google search, which is a common problem, is that I don't know what to search for, and when I try I get bizarre results. Or I get results for clips that hold the screen in place, not the ones that hold the frame together. Can someone who is familiar with window installation tell me what this damn clip is called? Thanks.

Comment: @Dan, Try searching google on your phone.  Take a picture of the 2 broken  parts layed together and search the pic.  Sorry I should have been more concise on that. Also see my edit